# Lightgallery js showing image behind bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html

I am having problem in previewing images using lightgallery js. It shows image behind the modal.

[image]

I don't know why is this happening

This is my javascript code to run lightgallery js.

```
 <script>
    lightGallery(document.getElementById('lightgallery{{id}}'), {
    plugins: [lgAutoplay, lgComment, lgFullscreen, lgHash, lgPager, lgRotate, lgVideo, lgZoom, 
    lgThumbnail], 
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: You might be putting it on the wrong id.

Comment: Set the `z-index` of the image higher than the `z-index` of the modal.

Answer (score 0):

The `zindex` of the lightbox by default is `1050` (backdrop has `1040`). Bootstraps modal has `1055` (there are two components, modal & the backdrop). You have 2 possibilites now:

1 - lower the z-index of your bootstrap modal, either via the [variables](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/scss/_variables.scss#L1132) if you have a build step (set them lower than `1040`) or you override them via css `.modal { z-index: 1035; }`. Also do that for the backdrop (lower value than `1035`).

2 - increase the z-index for the lightbox via css, again, modal & backdrop. I would prefer this way (as you don't mess with bootstrap stuff which could cause other z-index problems).

```css
.lg-outer { z-index: 1100; }
.lg-backdrop { z-index: 1090; }
```

IF you have specificity issues (meaning, the changes don't get applied due to [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)) you could add an ID on the wrapper or use a hack and repeat the class (inspect via devtools so you can check).

```css
#your-id-on-the-body .lg-outer {}
#your-id-on-the-body .lg-backdrop {}

// or repeating the class also increases the specificity
.lg-outer.lg-outer.lg-outer {}
.lg-backdrop.lg-backdrop.lg-backdrop {}
```

Answer (score -1):

**try this :** put this script in main page button to show modal

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function (event) {
        var zIndex = 1040 + (10 * $('.modal:visible').length);
        $(this).css('z-index', zIndex);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.modal-backdrop').not('.modal-stack').css('z-index', zIndex - 1).addClass('modal-stack');
        }, 0);
    });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: any error in your ?